# Adding another project like openSSL to my project. Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, c, openssl, codeblocks

**My Goal**

I'm trying to add some crytpo-related security to a project I'm working on in C++. Sticking with a solution that's already been made, I opted for OpenSSL fips 2.0.7. I know that I don't want to rely on the machine I'm compiling on having the most up-to-date version of OpenSSL pre-installed. So I want to ship the code with OpenSSL headers included.

Unfortunately I'm new to the language, and just as well the IDEs / Compilers associated. Which puts me in the precarious position of knowing more about what the code does, and little about how to add it.

**Environment**

- Windows 7 (64 - bit)
- Code::Blocks 13:12
- GCC (via MinGW)

**What I've Tried**

Project > Add Files Recursively > OpenSSL folder in my project > in my code:

```
   #include <openssl/rsa.h>
```

Which doesn't compile, because it can't find the file. (This would be my preffered method of linking to the headers, because all the other errors involve openSSL being unable to find its own files, and fixing that would require a MASSIVE amount of refactoring. Next:

```
    #include <project_name/openssl/crypto/rsa/rsa.h>
```

This is how it suggests it to me. However, this gives me the error inside of rsa.h, which can't find another header file because it is the in the format of the first include. Which I can fix with the project location, but that would require me to fix it among the entire openSSL codebase * **shivers** *

Comment: If `openssl/rsa.h` is not in your compiler's default headers (which is likely, unless you've put it there intentionally), you need to enclose it in quotes, and point your compiler to it. Since you're using Code::Blocks, you can add an include path for your project; it should point to the directory that contains the `openssl` directory (which in turn contains `rsa.h`). If you're using `g++` directly, use the `-I` argument.

Comment: It is not an answer, but I strongly recommend you Linux, as a comfortable platform for developement.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions enendil. I develop on Linux regularly. I just need fast iteration times, making sure that Windows explicitly is supported.

Comment: @MoreAxes Still having issues getting the library includes. Going to projects>build options>search directories> and adding openssl to the compiler doesn't let me include the headers.

Comment: You're actually not supposed to add the `openssl` directory, but the one that contains it. Have you changed your include statement to `#include "openssl/rsa.h"`? The quotes are significant, they can't be angle brackets in this case.